# How do I prove that $f'(z)=0$ implies $f$ is constant?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $V$ be an open connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $f:V\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a function whose derivative is $0$ on $V$.

How do I prove that $f$ is a constant on $V$?

I know that $V$ is path-connected, but I don't know whether this helps.

Comment: Can you see the proof for a real-valued function on a real interval $(a,b)$, that if $f'(x)=0$ at every point in that interval, then $f$ is constant there?

Comment: @hardmath Yes sure. I know an argument by Fermat for that one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect any point to a point $z_0$ by a polygonal line. Along each segment you can write $f(z) = f(z_i + t (z_f - z_i))$, and write this as two real functions of the real variable $t$, one for the real part and one for the imaginary part. Write the derivative in terms of them, you see both components are zero along the segment, so both components are constant and the function itself is constant on that segment, and thus over each segment of the path, and so over the full region.

Comment: I succeed in proving the theorem in this way. Thank you. BTW, how do you define polygonal line precisely? I rather showed that given $\alpha,\beta$, there exist finite points $\alpha=z_0,\cdots,z_n=\beta$ such that $z_i-z_{i+1}$ is either purely imaginary or purely real, and the line segment connecting these two are in $V$, then apply Cauchy-Riemann equation. This formulation is precise but really messy when written in meta-language.

Comment: I know it is a mess to write up precisely, but it is easy to explain. BTW, straight lines between $z_i$ to $z_f$ are just $z=z_i + (z_f -z_i) t$ with real $t$ between 0 and 1. And my definition of a connected region if based on polygonals connecting any pairof points

Answer (score 7):

Use the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations):

$$
f(x + iy) = u(x, y) + iv(x, y)
$$

Where $u$ and $v$ are real valued functions.  We have the constraints:

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v }{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v }{\partial x} 
$$

Giving:

$$
f'(x + iy) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}
$$

If $f' = 0$ then we have that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 0$.  This then entails that $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 0$.  If $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0$ then $u = \alpha(y)$.  If you do *all* of them then you find that $u = \alpha(y) = \beta(x)$ and $v = \gamma(y) = \varphi(x)$.  The *only* way that $\alpha(y) = \beta(x)$ for *all* values of $x$ and $y$ is if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have no dependence on *either* $x$ or $y$ and thus are constants.  The same follows for $v$.  Therefore $u = A$ and $v = B$ and $f(z) = A + Bi$.

Comment: What are g and h?

Comment: I think you mistakenly reused the name $f$.

Comment: Yes, I did, ran out of variables (I already didn't like using $j$).

Comment: @user140374 The $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, and $\varphi$ are just _some_ functions of single variables.  Since the partial is $0$, the original multi-variable function must actually have been a function of a _single_ variable.  They must be equal so that $\alpha(y) = \beta(x)$.  Let's choose a value of $x = x_0$ and $y = y_0$, then we must have $\alpha(y_0) = \beta(x_0)$.  What if we change $y$?  Then $\alpha(y_0 + h) \neq \alpha(y_0)$ unless $\alpha(y_0 + h) = \alpha(y_0) = A$, some constant.  But if they aren't equal, then $\alpha(y_0 + h) \neq \beta(x_0)$, a contradiction.

Comment: @Jared I don't get it. Where your argument used 'connectedness'?

Comment: @user140374 If the domain is not connected, then you could have several distinct values for $f$ on each disconnected region.  It would basically be $f(z) = a_n$ when $z \in D_n$ and $\forall m, n: n\neq m \leftrightarrow D_n \cap D_m = \emptyset$.  This would mean that $f$ is _not_ exactly constant (although it should be a "constant step function").

Comment: This is a bad answer...it's a "hammer looking for a nail".

Answer (score 5):

Consider a point $z_0 \in V$. Now consider any other point $w \in V$. Since $V$ is connected, it is possible to find a curve starting at $z_0$ and ending at $w$. Let's call this curve $C_w$. We then have
$$f(w) - f(z_0) = \int_{C_w} f'(z) dz = \int_{C_w} 0 \cdot dz = 0$$
Hence, we have $f(w) = f(z_0)$. This is true for any $w \in V$. Hence, $f(w) = f(z_0)$ and hence $f(w)$ is a constant in $V$.

Comment: wait but, to clarify, you're assuming path connected  instead of connected?

Comment: wait never mind i remember now: open and connected subset of Rn implies path connected: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088685/showing-an-open-connected-subset-of-mathbbrn-is-path-connected

Comment: Do we need simply connected domain instead of open, connected domain for the above integral to be well-defined?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Choose a path $\gamma$ connecting two given points in $V$, and evaluate

$$\int_{\gamma} f'(z) dz$$

two different ways.

Comment: I haven't learned line integral though.. Isn't there a way to prove this not using line integral?

Comment: @user140374: Have you learned the regular multivariable line integral? You can just treat the function as a pair of real-valued functions with two real-valued inputs.

Comment: @user2357112 No, i haven't.

Comment: @user140374 In that case, what have you learned? (Please note that adding additional details to the original question when asking will help a lot in getting answers that are actually *relevant* to you.)

Comment: @user140374: Huh. You're doing complex analysis before multivariable calculus? Weird.

Comment: @user2357112 I did multivariable calculus long time ago but not precisely. The only precise part i have done in multivariable calculus is just inverse,implicit,rank theorem.

Comment: @T.Bongers I'm trying to understand your answer. Is it true that "For any distinct point $x,y$ in an open connected subset $V$, there exists a differentiable function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow V$ such that $f(0)=x,f(1)=y$?

Comment: @user140374 Yes, there is; but really all that's necessary for the path integrals to make sense is piecewise smooth.